# Changing Location of Config Files in NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, package.json

In a typical nextjs project I find myself with a number of root-level config files:

- tsconfig.json
- next.config.js
- next-seo-config.ts
- .eslintrc
- etc...

I would like to clean up my root directory and move these files into their own directory.  In particular, I would like to create a `config` directory which would house the above files.

Is this possible in nextjs?  If so, how can I do it?

Thanks.